# 'chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function()' don`t run other functions

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

My function "someFunc" is started by clicking on the button, but does not start when receiving a request. Any thoughts?

```
var someVariable = 'someText';

function someFunc(message)
{
    alert(message);
}

$('#someBtn').click(function()
{
    someFunc(someVariable); //this run
    someFunc(); //this run
}   

chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse)
{
    if (request.action == 'login_on')
    {
      alert(request.action); //this work
      someFunc(request.action); // this don`t run
    }
});
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Out of curiosity, try this:

```
var someFunc = function(message){
    alert(message);
    return true;
}
```

BTW, your example works perfectly well for me.

Answer (score 0):

Alerts often mess things up. For example if you try to run `alert()` from a popup page it won't show up but stop further code from execution. I would recommend replacing alerts with `console.log` and see if it helps.

Comment: I don't need the alert. I wrote it for an example. Without the alert too does not work.

`chrome.extension.onRequest.addListener(function(request, sender, sendResponse)


{


 if (request.action == 'login_on')
 {

  ocsAlert(request.action); //this dont run

 }

});`

Comment: @user721153 You need to put `console.log` everywhere and figure out what exactly works and what exactly doesn't. In your original question you said that `alert(request.action); //this work`, so the request is being received then? Maybe it is your `ocsAlert()` that doesn't work? It will be just a guessing game without debugging.

Comment: function "ocsAlert()" works. It does not runs from the function of the request. And I don`t know why..
"ocsAlert()" it is a "someFunc()".

Comment: @serg how do you note this behavior? I'm sending alerts fine from popup.html connected to input buttons inside the popup, but I'm also pulling my hair with alerts that seemingly do not work but should. It won't show up 100% of the time?

Comment: @Chamilyan Just don't use alerts, it is medieval way of debugging code. Console.log is the way to go.